# iis reverse proxy showing error 404 for services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, arr

I have Asp.net MVC 4 Application with WCF services. Project is hosted in iis Production Server P125 (10.10.10.125), there are few other sites hosted in same server. Our Web / Front End Server is working as Reverse proxy for production server (Url Rewrite and Application Request Routing installed) As,

185.132.x.x is public ip of Web Server acting as reverse proxy only (Windows Server 2016).

Our application is hosted at port **8899** of Application server ip 10.10.10.125

185.132.x.x:8080  <= reverse proxy => 10.10.10.125:8899

Website is working fine, all the pages/actions are working fine of MVC application, except the services (**rest.svc , winact.svc**)

whenever we hit **185.132.x.x:8080/rest.svc** its showing error :

```
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /rest.svc
```

**I dont know why ?**
all our services are showing same error, while the services are working fine with **10.10.10.125:8899/rest.svc**  on local network as well as from the WebServer itself.

On remote login to WebServer(185.132.x.x) and browsing/accessing the application and services (**.svc**) via **10.10.10.125:8899**, its working fine.

I am using the Reverse Proxy as :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.10.10.125:8899/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
            
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

After spending 48 hours i have figured out that, configuring `serviceHostingEnvironment` resolved the issue of services (**.svc**) and my *Web.config* on WebServer(185.132.x.x) is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://10.10.10.125/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```